# create database in sql server 2005 express edition without Browser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I have an SQL server Express edition Instance and I need to create a database on it but I don't have the Sql Browser
how can I do it other wise

Comment: Do you mean SQL Management studio? The SQL Browser is a background service unrelated to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

**You can connect using "Server Explorer" in Visual studio** (menu View, Server Explorer).

This window allows you to connect to an existing database (Sql2000, 2005, 2008, access).

Once you are able to connect you can:

- Use CREATE DATABASE commands
- (Best) Create a visual studio database project and use deployed script to create Database.

If you want you can setup database project to automatically deploy to a DB.

Comment: the question is to create a Database on a sql server 2005 and this is not available from server Explorer in visual studio

Comment: You can connect to DB and later use Create database SQL command.. or better than this you could create a DB Project in visual studio and use its deploy script...

Comment: Edited my answer to include comment in it.

Answer (score -1):

hope these links can help you:

http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/26/create-a-table-in-sql-server-compact-edition-with-c/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB11282005064852AM/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB.aspx